# Confused about docker build to keep running docker container forever

Tags: linux, docker

So, I was playing around with Docker for the first time. What I did was to have an Open SSH server running on the container, so that I can logon to it from anywhere. It works fine when I used the following for docker build. Open SSH server was already installed in the base image.

```
#Download base image
FROM BaseImage
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

If I run the container with the following

```
docker run -p 52022:22 -dit <MyContainerID>
```

And Logon to it from outside, like this,

```
ssh -p 52022 <userName>@<IPAddress>
```

I can login fine.

But then I changed my docker file to something more general purpose, by replacing the last command with what is shown below, because I read from the internet that `CMD tail -f /dev/null` is a way to keep the docker container running.

```
CMD service ssh start
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

However, now If I try to login from outside, I get the following error.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

What is the reason? How come this is not working. The command `service ssh start` should had started the SSH server in the background, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem. In docker, you can use CMD just once. So, instead of

```
CMD service ssh start
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

It should be,

```
CMD service ssh start && \
    tail -f /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would just clarify the situation here a little. With regard to how to use the `CMD` instruction and also with respect to `ENTRYPOINT`, that I think you should consider using here.

The `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions in a Dockerfile, help us specify what command should be run when the image is started, and what arguments it should receive.

Generally what you want to do is to have the `ENTRYPOINT` specify an executable or script that should be invoked. Common practice is to have an `entrypoint.sh` or `docker-entrypoint.sh` script here.

The `CMD` command is then used to specify parameters to the entrypoint script.

So with `ENTRYPOINT ["ping"]` and `CMD ["localhost"]`, the container would start with the command `ping localhost`.

From the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The main purpose of a `CMD` is to provide defaults for an executing
>   container

So for your instance, I would use: `CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]` - if you need to send anything else to the container on startup, make an entrypoint script that takes those parametes, set the script as the `ENTYPOINT` and at the end of it start the process `/usr/sbin/sshd -D`.

I believe that you may be trying to tail your sshd log here, in order to have it piped to the stdout and stderr. With the `-D` flag to sshd, your process will not become a daemon, but stay in the foreground of the session that it was executed in. And with docker, this is exactly what you want. Docker is aready logging everything sent to stdout and stderr, and you want to make use of this. If your sshd process is not already logging to stdout and stderr, then you could configure it to do so in your Dockerfile.

I would recommend that you read this article, for what you are doing: [Dockerize an SSH service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a question. This script works fine, `FROM MyBaseImage
CMD service ssh start && \
       tail -f /dev/null`
But If I make a script start.sh with the following contents,
`#!/bin/bash
service ssh start
tail -f /dev/null`
And then use the docker file with this,
`FROM MyBaseImage
COPY start.sh .
RUN chmod u+x start.sh
ENTRYPOINT start.sh`
It doesn't work. Any idea, why?

Comment: Hi. The reason that it is working is that you container will keep running as long as the `tail`command is active. That in effect should be the PID 1 in your container. Which is not the intention with docker, it is an anti-pattern. To see why it does not work with the `start.sh`, I would have to see the error. But I would advise against using the service manager to start your sshd service, and from using tail in a container to keep it alive. Instead just start it as a foreground process. One container should have only one process inside. If you need more processes, consider more containers.

Comment: If you need remote shell access to containers, docker already provides this service. There really is not a lot of cases that calls for a sshd service. Try using something like [portainer](https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/portainer/) for example. That will allow you to start shell sessions in all the containers on your host, from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is only last CMD is considered by Docker build instructions 
so you need to combine your both CMDs into one single command.